# How to find rows that sum up to certain values of colSums and rowSums?

Tags: r

My task is to randomly assign 8 rows that consist of 12 columns and values that are random combinations of 0 and 1 values while each row sum equals 6 and each column sum equals 4.

So I create all possible combinations of 0 and 1 within 12 variables:

```
df <- expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 
                   0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1, 0:1)
```

Restrain possible combinations to these that row sum equals 6:

```
df <- df[rowSums(df)==6,]
```

Then I shuffle it:

```
shuffled <- df[sample(nrow(df)),]
```

and finally I'd like to pick 8 rows from shuffled data. All these 8 rows must have column sums that equal 4 and row sums equal 6:

```
colSums(picked_shuffled)
[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4

rowSums(picked_shuffled)
[1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it by trial and error will take you a very long time!  An alternative is to construct a matrix that works and then shuffle it...

```
rows <- rep(1:8, 6)                    #48 row positions for the 1s - 6 of each
columns <- rep(1:12, each = 4)         #48 column positions for the 1s - 4 of each

mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 8, ncol = 12)  #blank matrix of 0s

mat[cbind(rows, columns)] <- 1         #set selected values to 1

mat <- mat[sample(1:8), sample(1:12)]  #shuffle rows and columns

mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1     1     0     1
[2,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0     1     0
[3,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0     1     0
[4,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1     1     0     1
[5,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1     1     0     1
[6,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0     1     0
[7,]    1    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    1     1     0     1
[8,]    0    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    0     0     1     0
```

I don't know if it is possible to produce a more "random" distribution than this - there are still only two types of column and two types of row however you shuffle it!

By the way these operations are usually much faster on matrices than dataframes - you can always convert it at the end.

**A more random solution...**

After a bit of thought, it is possible to get a more "random" solution with the method above, but shuffling `columns` until you get no duplicated row-column pairs (which seems to be quite fast).  So a modified version...

```
rows <- rep(1:8, 6)
columns <- sample(rep(1:12, 4))

while(any(duplicated(cbind(rows, columns)))){
  columns <- sample(columns)
}

mat <- matrix(0, nrow = 8, ncol = 12)

mat[cbind(rows, columns)] <- 1

mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    0    1    0     1     1     0
[2,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    0     0     1     0
[3,]    1    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    0     1     0     1
[4,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    1    1     1     0     0
[5,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     0     1     1
[6,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    1    1     0     0     1
[7,]    1    0    1    1    1    1    0    0    0     1     0     0
[8,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1    1     0     1     1

rowSums(mat)
[1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

colSums(mat)
[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Comment: Clean, simple and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: @Tom I have added a refinement to generate a more random version - see above.

Answer (score 1):

I have got a less clean but more random solution to the problem than Andrew. It randomly shoots `1` at the initially empty grid, until the conditions are satisfied. Sometimes, it removes 20% of previous hits to prevent getting stuck. When it gets stuck because of too many iterations, it resets.

I simulated it and it usually takes about 40-80 iterations to fill the grid according to your specifications. In rare cases, it takes up to 160.

```
  grid = matrix(0,nrow=8,ncol=12)
  finished = F
  count=0
  while(!finished){
    openrows = c(1:8)[rowSums(grid)<6]
    opencols = c(1:12)[colSums(grid)<4]
    if(length(openrows)>0 & length(opencols)>0){
      if(length(openrows)==1 & length(opencols)==1 & grid[openrows[1],opencols[1]]==1){
        grid[grid==1 & runif(length(grid),0,1)>0.8]=0
      }
      i = as.integer(runif(1,0,length(openrows)))+1
      j = as.integer(runif(1,0,length(opencols)))+1
      grid[openrows[i],opencols[j]]=1
    }else{
      finished=TRUE
    }
    count = count+1
    if(count>500){
      grid = matrix(0,nrow=8,ncol=12)
      count=0
      }
  }
```

It's not very efficient (for large tables) but it works and gives you random data.
That was quite the brain teaser, tbh.